# How to select a row in Angular 5

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, data-binding, datatables, selection

I'm verrryyyyy new to Angular, so please understand me :)

I have a list of users, that are displayed like this:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

**EDIT - ADDED CRUD BUTTONS :**

```
  <!--Add new button-->
  <button type="button" (click)="AddModal.show()">
  </button>

  <button type="button" (click)="EditModal.show()">
  </button>

  <button type="button" (click)="DeleteModal.show()">
  </button>

</div>
<!--Data Tableq which displays users info-->
<div class="dash-table-container">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Name
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
        </th>
        <th>
          Position
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
        </th>
        <th>
         Office
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
        </th>
        <th>
         Age
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
        </th>
        <th>
         Salary
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <!--<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>-->
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let u of users; let i=index;">
        <td>{{u.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{u.Position}}</td>
        <td>{{u.Office}}</td>
        <td>{{u.Age}}</td>
        <td>{{u.StartDate}}</td>
        <td>{{u.Salary}}</td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<app-product-new #AddModal></app-group-new>

<app-product-edit #EditModal></app-group-edit>

<product-dialog #DeleteModal></touch-dialog>
```

I'm wondering how could I select a row from this table using angular?
I need that because I want to send that selected row's data to a modal for editing..

**EDIT:**

So basically, when I select a row and when I click on a EDIT modal I would like to know which row is selected so I can populate modal's data with that informations and save/edit it..

Thanks

Thanks guys!
Cheers

Comment: add click handler to your `<tr *ngFor="let u of users; let i=index;" (click)="RowSelected(u)">` and open the modal on this click handler to modify data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you want that for edit or something , I have added below a button with each row on click of which you will get complete row.

```
  <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let u of users; let i=index;">
            <td>{{u.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Position}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Office}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{u.StartDate}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Salary}}</td>
            <td> <input type="button" value="Edit" (click)="RowSelected(u)"/></td>
          </tr> 
        </tbody>

RowSelected(u:any){
console.log(u);
}
```

**Update:**

If you dont want button on each row and get data of selected row by just clicking on row, below is the code.

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let u of users; let i=index;" (click)="RowSelected(u);">
            <td>{{u.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Position}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Office}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{u.StartDate}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Salary}}</td>
            </td>
          </tr> 
        </tbody>
```

**For Edit in Question:**

After above code in html, in your component.

```
RowSelected(u:any){
this.selectedUser=u;   // declare variable in component.
}
```

Again in your modal.

```
<modal>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.Name" />
<input type="text" ([ngModel)]="selectedUser.Position" />
...
...
</modal>
```

Comment: but what if my button is separated from a <td> ? how can I store selected user and send it to that button?

Comment: check for my Edit's please, vote up for your help! :)

Comment: Updated Answer. It should be easy :)

Comment: Thanks man, that's what I wanted. One more thing is how could I send this selected object to a EDIT MODAL which is a part of my user-lists components, so it's nested component :D

Comment: Which modal are you using? Can you show code? You don't need to explicitly send data to modal, data will be blinded always as I have shown in code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168379/discussion-between-billy-56-and-dheeraj-kumar).

Answer (score 5):

```
    You can try this following source code
    **app.component.ts**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    users = [
        {Name: 'karthi', Position: 'Developer', Office: 'a2z', Age: 29, StartDate: '11Nov2018', Salary: 2000, flag: false},
        {Name: 'arun', Position: 'Tester', Office: 'a2z', Age: 29, StartDate: '11Nov2018', Salary: 5000, flag: false},
        {Name: 'mani', Position: 'Software analyst', Office: 'a2z', Age: 29, StartDate: '11Nov2018', Salary: 6000, flag: false},
        {Name: 'viay', Position: 'Developer', Office: 'a2z', Age: 29, StartDate: '11Nov2018', Salary: 21000, flag: false},
    ];
    public selectUsers(event: any, user: any) {
       user.flag = !user.flag;
      }

    }

    **app.component.html**
    <!--Data Tableq which displays users info-->
    <div class="dash-table-container">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Name
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
            </th>
            <th>
              Position
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
            </th>
            <th>
             Office
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
            </th>
            <th>
             Age
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
            </th>
            <th>
             Salary
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-up sorting-icon" style="display: none;"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-sort sorting-icon-default"></i>
            </th>
        </thead>
        <!--<tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>-->
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let u of users; let i=index;" (click)="selectUsers($event, u);" [class.selected]="u.flag === true">
            <td>{{u.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Position}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Office}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{u.StartDate}}</td>
            <td>{{u.Salary}}</td>
          </tr> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    **app.component.css**
    .selected{background-color:#B0BED9}
```

Comment: I was looking for adding background and sort code. Thx!